# Differentiability of power series on $\text{Hom}(\mathbb{R}^n, \mathbb{R}^n)$.

Tags: analysis, multivariable-calculus, derivatives, vector-spaces, normed-spaces

Let $L = \text{Hom}(\mathbb{R}^n, \mathbb{R}^n)$ be the normed vector space equipped with the operator norm, and $\sum_{n\geq0} a_nt^n$ a power series with radius of convergence R. Take $B(0,r) \subset L$ to be the open ball of radius $r$ centered about the origin. We can define $s_n: B(0,r) \rightarrow L$ for $r<R$ given by $s_n(H)=\sum_{k=0}^n a_kH^k.$

It can be shown that the sequence of functions $(s_n)_{n\geq 0}$ converges uniformly on $B(0,r)$ to a limit s(H).

Q: How do we prove that $s$ is differentiable at $H=0$?

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score 0):

You prove this using the definition of derivative; i.e. we need to show that there exists a linear function $Ds(0):L\to L$ such that
$$
\lim_{\| T\|\to 0} \dfrac{\| s(H+T)-s(H)- Ds(0)[T]\|}{\| T\|} =0.
$$
You can check that, under your conditions, the function $Ds(0)[T]= a_1 T$ satisfies the above (since all the terms that survive in $s(T)$ have powers of $T$ higher than 2).

Comment: Thanks for the answer, just a follow up question - the result here is very weak compared to the result we have on the real line. Is it possible to prove/disprove the differentiability of s on the entire ball?